# What parameters should one pass to an immutable class constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, immutability

Often times we want to construct them from a database, but we might also want to create fakes for testing, or load from a file.

Should we have a constructor that takes :

1. An IDataReader
2. Every single field.
3. A mutable version of the class, so a repo can create the mutable version, update it, and then convert to an immutable version with this constructor?
4. Something else entirely

I don't like option 1 because it means every class needs to know about `System.Data`, 2 seems ok but seems to require a lot of maintenance anytime we want to add a field, and 3 seems ok too but also maintenance anytime a field is added (though less than 2.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable objects are often constructed by creating a builder and then set all properties to it that are relevant and finally calling `Commit()` to retrieve the immutable version of it.

I am personally pretty fond of a "fake" immutable class that looks like this:

```
public interface IPlanet
{
    string Name { get; }
}

internal class PlanetBuilder : IPlanet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IPlanet Commit()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The good with this structure is that it is pretty small overhead to write. The `Commit()` method can even be refactored into a generic base class.

The bad with it is that anyone can tamper with the object by casting it back to its factory class type.

Comment: +1 for pointing out yet another approach I hadn't thought of.  And yes it's unfortunate they can cast it back if they knew what built it.  I think you need to have your PlanetBuilder implement IPlanet though.

Comment: @user420667 On the other hand, if you don't "trust" your object users to use the objects as intended, you need to be wary they can always reflect into the object and change stuff under your feet. If you don't trust the sender of an object you should always validate the entire object before you use it - don't trust it because it "should" be self-validated.

Comment: @user420667 "you need to have your PlanetBuilder implement IPlanet" OOpps! That was kind of the most important point! Fixed the example. Thanks